# How can I add my app version on Android Studio Giraffe?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to add My App Version on TextView in Android Studio Giraffe.
I tried
`TextView version = findViewById(R.id.version); version.setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);`
but it didn't worked for me.

Please tell me the code !!!!!!!!

Comment: Probably you have no versionName property set in your build.gradle file, it's reason why this code returns null.

Answer (score 0):

To get app version, you can use `PackageManager` API to access version info. See the below code.

```
// you can also add condition for null.
PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert pInfo != null;
        // store your version name (version code) in String.
        TextView version = findViewById(R.id.version);
        String appVersion = pInfo.versionName;
        version.setText(appVersion);
```

If you have any doubt, let me know.

Comment: Thanks al lot!  It worked for me.

Comment: @Dostovsky check this as an answer if you found this helpful.